# Why ApplicationInsights.config file was ignored automatically from being added to Github Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio, github, git-clone

I created a **asp.net mvc** project in **VisualStudio** and published it in **Github**. I noticed that the `ApplicationInsights.config` file was ignored by default.

Now the project can not be compiled when cloned due to this file is missing. After that I added it manually to the repo and everything worked as expected.

Why was this file ignored by default? Is it a bad practice to add this file to the repository?

Comment: It might be a problem when the InstrumentationKey is listened in there? One could abuse that information.

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was because someone thought that there are secrets in this file based on discussion like this one:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1815